# validar input que se autocompleta con array de php

Tags: php, javascript

Necesito validar un `input` dentro de un formulario que se autocompleta con un array `php` ya que si el usuario no selecciona una de las opciones que se autocompletan el formulario igual busca.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que utilizo para autocompletar es el siguiente,

```
<?php
  include 'ciudades.php';
  if(!empty($_POST['inputciudades'])){
    $ciudad=$_POST['ciudades'];
  }
?>

<script>
  $(function(){
    var vec_ciu_trf=new Array();
   <?php
     for($c_trf = 0;$c_trf < count($arreglo_ciudad);$c_trf++){?>
       vector_ciudad_trf.push('<?php echo$arreglo_ciudad[$c_trf];?>');
   <?php }?>
    $("#inputciudades").autocomplete({
      source:vector_ciudad
    });
  });
</script>
<input type="text" name="inputciudades" id="inputciudades"></input>
```

**SOLUCIONADO** dejo la solucion a continuacion  si no se selecciona un item de la lista se limpia el input y detiene la ejecucion del form ( ya que este es requerido )

```
$("#inputciudades").autocomplete({
      source:vector_ciudad,
change: function(e, ui) {
if (!ui.item) {
    $(this).val("");
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Quieres validar el formulario antes de enviarlo (_con `JS`_) o quieres validar que haya algo en la variable (_con `PHP`_) o ambos? (_deberías hacer ambos_) ¿Ya has hecho otras validaciones en `JS`? ¿Que tipo de mensaje espera que vea el usuario (_alert, msj `HTML`, etc._)?

Comment: Marcos , lo correcto imagino es que con js ( prefiero php ) busque que el texto ingresado en el input este en el array antes que se ejecute el formulario

Comment: ¿Exactamente que autocomplete JS esta usando?  jquery

Comment: ¿Cual de todos? Agregar el enlace

Comment: Marcos , ya lo solucione , la clave fue tu pregunta , si jquery autocompletaba era obvio que tambien validaba .

Comment: Leonardo, genial! seria bueno que publiques una respuesta con la solución. Saludos!

Comment: Ya la agregue al posteo , fijate donde dice SOLUCION

Comment: Leonardo, seria mejor que crees una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

primero no es recomendable tener codigo embebido de `php` y `javascript` lo ideal seria que hagas una peticion ajax, pero si el caso es necesario deberias de separar un poco la logica, capturando el array en una variable de js y luego hacer todo el trabajo en el, ya que el proceso de compilacion en este caso no lo hace en orden de codigo, por el contrario compila primero el `php` entonces cuando haga los ciclos va a estar vacio, dicho esto te pongo un ejemplo tratando de seguir tu logica:

```
<?php
include 'ciudades.php';
if(!empty($_POST['inputciudades']))
    $ciudad=$_POST['ciudades'];
}
?>

<script>
    $(function(){
        var vec_ciu_trf = new Array();

        var ciudades = '<?php echo $arreglo_ciudad;?>';

        for (let j = 0; j < ciudades.length; j++) {
            vec_ciu_trf.push(ciudades[j]);
        }

        $("#inputciudades").autocomplete({
            source:vec_ciu_trf
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="text" name="inputciudades" id="inputciudades"></input>
```

aunque a decir verdad creeria que con solo pasar el elemento ciudades serviria, es decir asi,

el script quedaria asi:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var ciudades = '<?php echo $arreglo_ciudad;?>';
    $("#inputciudades").autocomplete({
        source:ciudades
    });
});
```

Bueno, espero te sirva, me cuentas...

Comment: srJJ , completar autocompleta perfecto , lo que no puedo hacer es validar , ya que tambien lo puedo hacer por ajax , pero por ejemplo "BUE" me sugiere "BUENOS AIRES" pero si no selecciono "BUENOS AIRES" el formulario se ejecuta igualmente con "BUE" , y la busqueda va a ser incorrecta.

Comment: Esto no debería funcionar, dado que `echo []` genera una advertencia `Array to string conversion` y el resultado es `Array`. Una corrección seria utilizar [`echo json_encode($arrelgo);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Además no has dado solución al problema que plantea en la pregunta.

Comment: @leonardosebastian lo que puedes hacer en este caso es antes de enviar validar que el valor tipeado este dentro del array que que se ha generado, ahora bien, deberias de poner el codigo en donde envias en formulario para ver como se puede adaptar para validar ya que es autocomplete es una una sugerencia mas no una obligacion, edita la pregunta pon el codigo de como envias la el formulario

Comment: @Marcos, la verdad no entiendo por que deberia dar error si php como javascript son flexibles y a mi no me ha generado error, en todo caso si es asi, seria seguir tu recomendacion, y por lo otro necesitaria el codigo de el para validar, de igual forma lo siento si mi respuesta no es suficiente, espero la tuya sea mejor. gracias :)

Comment: @srJJ, [acá vas a poder ver lo que intenté explicar](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5de992ab8c2ad99b0b14dc37c811556b16744909). Por otro lado, tu respuesta se basa en tu opinión sobre emeber `PHP` en `JS`, que nada tiene que ver con la pregunta. Si OP responde a mis preguntas, recién entonces considero que vale la pena responder.

Comment: @Marcos ese test siempre fallara por que los includes no estan y la variable de arreglo no existe, por otra parte, Maestro solo pretendo ayudar, y a su vez si es necesario aprender de mi errores. gracias por la observacion.

Comment: @srJJ, me parece que aún no me he podido dar a entender en cuanto a que `echo $arreglo`, donde `$arreglo` es un `array` cualquiera el resultado  es una cadena igual a `Array`. Es decir que el resultado de esto `var ciudades = '<?php echo $arreglo_ciudad;?>';` es igual a esto `var ciudades = 'Array';`, esta mal. Se que tu intención es ayudar, y es por esto que me tome la molestia de comentar a tu respuesta.